# python module re throwing odd AttributeError

Tags: python

I've always used the re module to do things such as re.match and re.sub, the basic stuff, and it's always worked fine for me.

All of a sudden, I'm getting an AttributeError when trying to use basic methods such as match and sub.

Here is some example code I made:

```
import re

regex = '^[a-z]{3}'
r = re.match(regex, 'asd')
print r
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "te.py", line 4, in <module>
    r = re.match(regex, 'asd')
AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'match'
```

I've never had problems with the module. I tried in both python 2.x and 3, same error. I'm not very knowledgeable about how imports work, so this is likely a simple mistake by me.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a python code in the same folder named re.py? Can you do a dir(re) in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your `re.py` file in the same directory as the `te.py` file. You commited a typo while naming test files. Your error points that your current file is named `te.py`, and since `t` is close to `r` in the keyboard, this might explain everything.

Just to prove my curiosity I created an empty re.py file in the same directory as te.py, which holds your code. And I got the same error as you did.

Comment: When you said there may be a file overwriting the re module, you were right. In the directory, I had a file named re.py for whatever reason. Deleted it and the .pyc file and things work fine now, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're getting something you don't expect for the `re` module that you're importing.

Maybe try this:

```
import re
print re.__file__
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.pyc
```

And see if the result you get is sensible.

Comment: The only thing I got back was re.pyc, which is a cache file I believe

Comment: If you got 're.pyc', then I believe that means it was getting an re module from the same directory you're running the script from. Is that what you expect?

Comment: Turns out, I had a file named re.py in the same directory. I deleted it and now things work as expected. It's just weird because I've never had this problem, that file has always been in there.